# Apply Map for NaN rows in DataFrame, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, map-function

Topic_Details

```
                   Topic Source_Code      Anchor            Sub_Topic_Dataset            Dataset_Id
42  Macroeconomic Accounting Systems      GESAMT              Financial Accounts ESA 1995    DBB_GESAMTFAE12019
43  Macroeconomic Accounting Systems      GESAMT  GESAMTFINZ  Financial Accounts ESA 2010  DBB_GESAMTFINANZ2019
44  Macroeconomic Accounting Systems      GESAMT  GESAMTVOLK            National Accounts    DBB_GESAMTVOLK2019
```

Dataset_List:

```
       anchor                     text_eng            Dataset_Id
0  GESAMTVOLK            National             DBB_GESAMTVOLK2019
0  GESAMTFINZ  Financial accounts           DBB_GESAMTFINANZ2019
0              Financial accounts ESA 1995                   NaN
```

Map Script:

```
MapDF = dict(zip(Topic_Details['Sub_Topic_Dataset'].str.upper(), Topic_Details['Dataset_Id']))
Dataset_List['Dataset_Id'] = Dataset_List['text_eng'].apply(str.upper).map(MapDF)
```

I just want to run below script for the Dataset Dataset_List where Dataset_Id == NaN, not for other rows.

```
Dataset_List['Dataset_Id'] = Dataset_List['text_eng'].apply(str.upper).map(MapDF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing the result of `apply` to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```py
Dataset_List['Dataset_Id'].fillna(Dataset_List['text_eng'].apply(str.upper).map(MapDF), inplace=True)
```

It can accept a Series as a value, and for every NaN it uses the value with same index.

Comment: what do you mean? `fillna` will not change values of row that is not NaN

Comment: Sorry there was my mistake, your answer correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
desired_subset = Dataset_List[Dataset_List['Dataset_Id'].isnull()]
desired_subset['Dataset_Id'] = desired_subset['text_eng'].apply(str.upper).map(MapDF)
```